# Can we maximize the log of the odds instead of log of the probability?

Tags: probability, optimization, likelihood, odds

As above. This question relates to all optimization formulations in statistics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, because if you have two different probabilities $p_1$ and $p_2$ with $p_1 < p_2$, the following are all equivalent:
\begin{align}
p_1 & < p_2 \\
- p_1 & > - p_2 \\
1 - p_1 & > 1 - p_2 \\
\frac{1}{1 - p_1} & < \frac{1}{1 - p_2}
\end{align}
because applying an increasing function does not reverse the inequality (like $f(x) = x + 1$ from line 2 to 3) while applying a decreasing function (like $g(x) = -x$ from lines 1 to 2 and $h(x) = 1/x$ for positive values of $x$ from lines 3 to 4) does reverse the inequality. Then multiplying the first and last lines gives you
$$
\frac{p_1}{1 - p_1} < \frac{p_2}{1 - p_2}.
$$
These are also equivalent to $\log(p_1) < \log(p_2)$ and
$$
\log \left( \frac{p_1}{1 - p_1} \right) < \log \left( \frac{p_2}{1 - p_2} \right)
$$
because $\log$ is an increasing function.

Comment: From your experience, have you seen examples of problems where this is done indeed?
in deeplearning we always go after log of likelihood / prob.

Comment: I've never seen an example. You would want to choose whichever made the optimization an easier problem to solve. If using the log odds $\log(p/(1-p)) = \log(p) - \log(1 - p)$ simplifies the problem, then it would be good to use it. But I think minimizing $\log(p)$ is typically easier than trying to minimize log odds $\log(p) - \log(1 - p)$ unless the problem has a form that is simplified by this, since the latter includes the former as a subexpression.